# python classes bound and unbound error

Tags: python

```
from string import *
import math

class Shape(object):
    def area(self):
        raise AttributeException("Subclasses should override this method.")

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self, h):
        """
        h: length of side of the square
        """
        self.side = float(h)
    def area(self):
        """
        Returns area of the square
        """
        return self.side**2
```

How do I enable the method area so that it returns the value. Is shape some sort of superclass?
I have tried things like

```
p=Shape(3.0)
```

or

```
p=Square(3.0)
```

then

```
p.area
```

Comment: You didn't try too much, did you? How about `p.area()`? :)

Comment: Btw: you should use `NotImplementedError` to tell the user that subclasses must implement that error. `AttributeException` doesn't even exist: it's called `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 2):

Methods need  to be called to return a value:

```
p = Square(3.0)
p.area()  # Notice the ()
```

More specifically:

- `p.area` is the method itself.
- `p.area()` calls the method and returns its value.

Answer (score 0):

You create the object Square :

```
s = Square(3.0)
```

The **init** method is called and you have now access to the value s.side.

You can call the methods of the object.

```
Ar = s.area()
```

Ar contains the value returned by the method area() of the object.